# Python using Regex find a string with dynamic value in a big string

Tags: python, regex

I have a very large string and I like to find a small string or value inside it (in my example 14). A snippet of it looks like this:

I need to retrieve 14. The catch is that 78 is dynamic and I get it's value  from a dict (someDict)

```
str1='dnas  ANYTHING Here <td class="tr js-name"><a href="/myportal/report/78/abc/xyz/14" title="balh">blah</a></td>'

str2="/myportal/report/"+str(someDict["Id"])+"/abc/xyz/"

p = re.compile(r'str2\s*(.*?)\"')
match = p.search(str1)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print("cant find it")
```

I know there is something wrong with --> `p = re.compile(r'str2\s*(.*?)\"')`  since I cant just stick in `str2`, how do I go about using compile please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string you are parsing looks like HTML, regular expressions [is not exactly the best tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/771848). I would a more specialized tool - an **HTML parser**, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = 'dnas  ANYTHING Here <td class="tr js-name"><a href="/myportal/report/78/abc/xyz/14" title="balh">blah</a></td>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
href = soup.select_one("td.tr.js-name > a")["href"]

parsed_url = urlparse(href)
print(parsed_url.path.split("/")[-1])
```

Prints `14`.

Note that here `td.tr.js-name > a` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that is one of the techniques you could use to locate elements in the HTML:

- `>` denotes a *direct* parent->child relationship
- `td.tr.js-name` would match a `td` element having `tr` and `js-name` class values

Comment: This is really cool thanks alecxe, so there is only one: td.tr.js-name > a   in html string right?

Comment: @user3556956 yeah, `.select_one()` would locate a single element only. `.select()` would locate multiple elements. BeautifulSoup is pretty flexible overall and there are tons of different ways to get to the desired elements.